# SBT fails to resolve dependency for jersey-container-grizzly2-http 2.5.1

Tags: scala, jersey, jax-rs, sbt

I am fairly new to Scala and SBT. I would like to implement a REST server using Jersey JAX-RS and Scala, but have faced the first hurdle trying to configure SBT. I was planning to use the Grizzly HTTP Server. The `build.sbt` is as follows:

```
name := "scala-jersey-server"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.jersey.containers" % "jersey-container-grizzly2-http" % "2.5.1"
```

Running sbt update fails with the following messages

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-utils;2.5.1: not found
[warn]  :: org.glassfish.hk2#hk2-locator;2.5.1: not found
[warn]  :: javax.validation#validation-api;${javax.validation.version}: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Looking at the `pom.xml` for `hk2-api`, it shows dependency on `hk2-utils` using the `${project.version}` variable, but I'd have expected version 2.2.0-b21 of `hk2-utils` to be requested by SBT not 2.5.1 (which is JAX-RS version).

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
   <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId> 
   <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this a problem with the configuration of hk2-api's pom.xml, is SBT using an incorrect version or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is an error in the publication chain of your dependency for the 2.5.1 version.

There are at least three possibilities:

**1. Use another version**

```
//http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.glassfish.jersey.containers%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jersey-container-grizzly2-http%22
libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.jersey.containers" % "jersey-container-grizzly2-http" % "2.5"
```

**2. Use another library**

**3. Exclude the broken dependencies and set working versions**
Use http://search.maven.org/ to find existing versions.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.jersey.containers" % "jersey-container-grizzly2-http" % "2.5.1" exclude("org.glassfish.hk2", "hk2-utils") exclude("org.glassfish.hk2", "hk2-locator") exclude("javax.validation", "validation-api")

//http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C703203458
libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.hk2" % "hk2-utils" % "2.2.0-b27"

//http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22hk2-locator%22
libraryDependencies += "org.glassfish.hk2" % "hk2-locator" % "2.2.0-b27"

//http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.validation%7Cvalidation-api%7C1.1.0.Final%7Cjar
libraryDependencies += "javax.validation" % "validation-api" % "1.1.0.Final"
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried the above .sbt file but it was not excluding the jars and was still giving the same ERROR.

So modified the build file. below sample it could create a build successfully.**

```
name := "KafkaSparkCouchReadWrite"

organization := "my.clairvoyant"

version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.0",
  "com.couchbase.client" %% "spark-connector" % "2.1.0",
  "org.glassfish.hk2" % "hk2-utils" % "2.2.0-b27",
  "org.glassfish.hk2" % "hk2-locator" % "2.2.0-b27",
  "javax.validation" % "validation-api" % "1.1.0.Final"
).map(_.excludeAll(ExclusionRule("org.glassfish.hk2"),ExclusionRule("javax.validation")))
```